# Opencv pattern/object Detection and rotation extraction

Tags: python, node.js, opencv

[image][image]

I've been working on black and white pattern detection using node js and also using python...I have a black and white square shaped pattern and need to detect the pattern and also detect the rotation of the pattern..where four sides of the pattern corresponds to four options.I first tried with Haar cascades and and used the camera feed rotation to detect the rotation of the pattern..but it is a heavier approach..as I'm trying to detect multiple patterns say 30..So  I just need to know how this can be solved..I've already tried contours based approach which didn't work for me..as the distance of the detection got heavily affected.

Comment: I did see svm and hog descriptors based detection...CAn it be executed in node js?...and how to train a SVM classifier

Comment: What did you mean with "distance of the detection got heavily affected"

Comment: are the patterns fixed or can they be strerched for example? Can they be rotated in 3D (perspective distortions) or only in 2D?

Comment: Its a 2d pattern..And i need to detect atleast 15-20 metres..contours is based on threshold values right..so when the light intensity changes the edges are not detected accurately

Comment: did you try to use color threshold ?

Comment: Yes, I did use color threshold